# What does it mean to "be how anxious" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in chapter "[The enemy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/levt104.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwir5qrY0JLiAhXGdn0KHXBwAkcQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw384-_Q7SNI1fdVJC9vVtDG)" in my book which was:

> She went obediently, but how anxious now to the linen shelves and took out the towels.

I don't know what "how" before "anxious" is doing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use 'how' as emphasis: how anxious she was! You omitted the punctuation:

> She went obediently, but how anxious now, to the linen shelves and
>   took out the towels.

She went obediently, but *how anxious she was* now, to the linen shelves and took out the towels.

> used for emphasis:
>
> I can't tell you **how** pleased I am (= I am very pleased) that you came.

[How (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/how)

Comment: But that usage of "how" is only to be seen only in interjectory sentences. May you quote some examples from any reliable dictionary to support your argument?

Comment: "How" used like that is not "only seen in interjectory sentences".